# Use phonegap or navigator.userAgent to detect Android tablet

Tags: android, cordova

I need to detect Android tablet like Google Nexus 7/10 or Samsung Galaxy Tab after OnDevice Ready.

I use device.platform and it just return Android only, unlike iOS, it return iPad.

I need to know that if I use the following to detect Android tablet, will it always return correct value if it's an Android Tablet?

```
if( /epad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
   // this is an Android tablet
}
```

I am using PhoneGap 2.1 and jqm 1.2.

cheers and regards,
Mark

**i discovered a method. what do u guys think? Any comment is appreciated : )**

```
if ($.event.special.orientationchange.orientation() === "portrait") {

    if($(window).width() > 420) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

} else {

    if($(window).width() > 660) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: It's really difficult to do this as all the user agent strings are different, particularly between browsers, as well as between manufacturers and devices. Here's the Nexus 7's: "*Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19*".

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You should be detecting screen sizes and capabilities.

Comment: if using screen sizes, how to figure out of what size a tablet is? like if width > 600 and height > 800 ? Anyone have these info?

Comment: using window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight is kind of tricky. if your code is say window.innerWidth > 400 mean it's a tablet, then you will get it wrong as when the orientation is landscape. this happen to the case like samsung galaxy when it's landscape, it shows 640x375 and when it's portrait, it shows 400x615. Any further advice guys ?

Comment: For anyone still looking for a solution, I've created a Cordova/Phonegap plugin for Android+iOS to detect whether the current device is a tablet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29943859/777265

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use phonegap [Device](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_device_device.md.html) plugin? It has a `platform`and `model`property that can help you. Using screen width and height to infer device identity is really bad practice.