# How to check weather the device is iPad and tablet in phonegap

Tags: cordova

How to check device in phonegap?.Actually i need that my application is only run only tablet or in Iphone .I need to block my application on other phones only run Android tablet or in iphone Ipad.is it possible to check in phonegap..?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

## Intro

There are several available solutions. Some are  provided by javascript, some are free and some are paid services. Plus some are server side and some are client side but from  this mail I think you need client side solutions.

## Client side detection:

**[Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)** -

> aking advantage of cool new web technologies is great fun, until you
>   have to support browsers that lag behind. Modernizr makes it easy for
>   you to write conditional JavaScript and CSS to handle each situation,
>   whether a browser supports a feature or not. It’s perfect for doing
>   progressive enhancement easily.

**Good :**

Only client side, server side component don't exist

Fast but still large for a javascript framework with its 12kb. Because of its modularity it can become smaller, depending on your needs.

**Bad :**

Can do only so much, less info then server side detection.

Modernizr itself is a great way to find out about your user’s browser capabilities. However, you can only access its API on the browser itself, which means you can’t easily benefit from knowing about browser capabilities in your server logic.

- It can be found here: http://modernizr.com/

Example :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Modernizr Example</title>
      <script src="modernizr.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        if (Modernizr.canvas) {
          // supported
        } else {
          // no native canvas support available :(
        }  
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**[JavaScript based browser sniffing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)**

> It is arguable that this may be (academically) the worst possible way
>   to detect mobile but it does have its virtues.

**Good :**

Simple

**Bad :**

It will only tell device type, but it will not provide device version. For example it will tell you that iPad us used but not if it is version 1,2 or 3.

**Example :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    var agent = navigator.userAgent;      
    var isWebkit = (agent.indexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0);      
    var isIPad = (agent.indexOf("iPad") > 0);      
    var isIOS = (agent.indexOf("iPhone") > 0 || agent.indexOf("iPod") > 0);     
    var isAndroid = (agent.indexOf("Android")  > 0);     
    var isNewBlackBerry = (agent.indexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0 && agent.indexOf("BlackBerry") > 0);     
    var isWebOS = (agent.indexOf("webOS") > 0);      
    var isWindowsMobile = (agent.indexOf("IEMobile") > 0);     
    var isSmallScreen = (screen.width < 767 || (isAndroid && screen.width < 1000));     
    var isUnknownMobile = (isWebkit && isSmallScreen);     
    var isMobile = (isIOS || isAndroid || isNewBlackBerry || isWebOS || isWindowsMobile || isUnknownMobile);     
    var isTablet = (isIPad || (isMobile && !isSmallScreen));     

    if ( isMobile && isSmallScreen && document.cookie.indexOf( "mobileFullSiteClicked=") < 0 ) mobileRedirect(); 
</script>
```

## More info

I have another article/answer about this topic. Find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055277/what-are-available-solutions-of-a-browser-mobile-phone-detection/15055352#15055352)**.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with JavaScript, using User Agent as already explain in another answer,

But you could also use the Cordova/PhoneGap  Device API

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/cordova_device_device.model.md.html#device.model

Using
var string = device.model;

string will contain the iOS model

Giving you all the information from the native just in case you want to know if its an iPad 1, iPad 2, or iPad Mini

For example "iPad2,5" is the iPad Mini Wifi

Check out this website for mapping information
http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

Answer (score 1):

Cordova "out-of-the-box" can't determine if a device is a tablet.

For iOS, a simple bit of Javascript can be used to detect if the device is an iPad by examining the user agent string:

```
var isTablet = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
```

However, for Android, JS isn't good enough, it requires some native Java:

```
private boolean isTabletDevice(Context applicationContext) {
        boolean device_large = ((applicationContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >=
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);

        if (device_large) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Is Tablet Device");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Is NOT Tablet Device");
        return false;
}
```

This plugin wraps up both these approaches in an easy-to-use package for Android and iOS: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-istablet.